# Can't get Tomcat 8 started on CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, tomcat

I’m trying to start up Apache Tomcat on a Google cloud server. It’s a CentOS 7 server and has Apache Tomcat 8 on it. Instructions are https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7 but when I get to:

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```

I get the message:

```
Job for tomcat.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status tomcat.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

For systemctl status tomcat.service I get:

```
tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-12-29 17:04:47 UTC; 639ms ago
Process: 3526 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Dec 29 17:04:47 jira-dev systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Dec 29 17:04:47 jira-dev systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

---

For journalctl -xe I can't post all of it because it "looks like spam" but I get:

```
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
Dec 29 16:55:33 jira-dev systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 29 16:55:33 jira-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

and

```
-- The result is failed.
Dec 29 16:55:33 jira-dev systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Dec 29 16:55:33 jira-dev systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
Dec 29 16:55:44 jira-dev systemd[1]: tomcat.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 29 16:55:44 jira-dev systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

and

```
-- Unit tomcat.service has begun starting up. Dec 29 16:55:44 jira-dev systemd[3317]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh: Permission denied
-- Subject: Process /opttomcat/bin/startup.sh could not be executed
-- Defined-By: systemd/
```

and

```
-- The error number returned by this process is 13.
Dec 29 16:55:44 jira-dev systemd[1]: tomcat.service: control process exited, code=exited status=203
Dec 29 16:55:44 jira-dev systemd[1]: Failed to start Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
-- Subject: Unit tomcat.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
```

The /etc/system/system/tomcat.service file looks like the one from the instructions.

I have also set `JAVA_HOME`, just in case.

I see the permission error, but I have given the tomcat user ownership of the tomcat directory as per [CentOs 7.1 - Install Tomcat 8](https://superuser.com/questions/1005383/centos-7-1-install-tomcat-8) with the `command cd /opt && sudo chown -R tomcat tomcat/`

I have also tried commenting out the `Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'` line from the tomcat.service file, although it didn't help, so I un-commented it.

I'm running as root.

Answer (score 1):

Since I ended up here and spent hours to figure it out

Error message

> systemd[5189]: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh: Permission denied

I solved it by giving execute permission to bin folder.